# SQL Server is unresponsive but SSMS and RDP connections work

Tags: database-administration

I have a production SQL server is unresponsive to our website, but I am still able to connect to it through management studio and remote desktop. How can I troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: How do you mean unresponsive? What type of response you tried?

Comment: [so] is not the place for broad open ended questions like this. Personally I would hire someone (dba, network analyst, applications developer, etc) to do some troubleshooting as it sounds like you do not know where to start.

Comment: I would have the DBA take a look at it.

Comment: The applications are not able to connect but I can RDP to the server and even use SSMS from a client to access the database on the server